# Missing results from SQL array

Tags: sql, database, resultset

I have a data set in my SQL table (pic related), and when I call back the results the first value is missing from the data set.

This is how I call back the data set:

```
$q = "SELECT o.*, f.*
    FROM opening_hours o
    LEFT JOIN farms f ON o.farm_id = f.id
    WHERE f.id = {$_GET['id']}
    ORDER BY weekday ASC";

$data_set = mysql_query($q, $connection);
confirm_query($data_set);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data_set)) {           
    echo $row['start_hour'] . "<br />";
}
```

The end result is to the right of the image.

[image]

Comment: So this question isn't about Sql but php or whatever language you are using to execute the query and handle the result?

Comment: Show us the result of var_dump($data_set);

Comment: Yes Joakim that's correct.

Comment: var_dump is the following: farms.php:78:resource(14, mysql result)

Comment: The result you have, is it from phpmyadmin or your website ?

Comment: The table is phpmyadmin, and the result is from my site (via WAMP)

Comment: What if you execute the query from phpmyadmin ?

Comment: It is fine on phpmyadmin

Comment: And what if you use mysql_fetch_assoc in your php code ? try to delete confirm_query too.

Comment: How do I use that?

Comment: This normally happens when you’ve written code that executes a query and returns some sort of enumerable collection of data, and it’s already pointing to the first row, then you say the equivalent of WHILE GET-NEXT-ROW  - I don’t know what this is in php, but the basic point is that in determining if the collection had data,  you just skipped the first row

Comment: Is there an alternative? I've never had this happen before

Comment: I discovered the reason it was happening was because of an earlier singular mysql_fetch_array I had used for one result!